# Directional Derivative, with no assumption of knowledge of directional derivatives!

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis

I'm not sure how to compute the directional derivative of some multivariable function, but I've come across an exercise which says "this is an example of a directional derivative" before they are actually introduced.

The exercise is as follows;

> Determine the slope of the surface $z = x^4 − y^2$ at the point $(1, 1)$ in the
>   general direction that makes an angle $\theta$ with the positive $x$-axis. Find a value of $\theta$ with $0 ≤ \theta ≤ \frac{\pi}{2}$ where this slope is zero. This is an example
>   of a directional derivative.

As there is an angle involved I thought I might transform to polar coordinates and then differentiate with respect to $r$ and $\theta$ but I'm not entirely sure where this would lead. Differentiating $z$ w.r.t. $x$ and $y$ and evaluating at $(1, 1)$ gives I believe $4$ and $-2$ respectively, but I'm (again) not sure how to interpret this result. Can anybody give me a hint/explain how I might go about solving a problem like this without simply giving a definition of the directional derivative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**: If you slice in direction $\theta$, you are looking at points of the form $(1+t\cos\theta,1+t\sin\theta)$. Letting $f(x,y)=x^4-y^2$, can you find the slope of the curve $z=f(1+t\cos\theta,1+t\sin\theta)$ at $t=0$?

Comment: is "slope of the surface" the correct word ? here at $(x,y,z)$ there is a tangent plane

Comment: @user1952009: No, we're talking about the slope of the plane curve we get when we slice with the vertical plane through $(1,1,0)$ in direction $\theta$.

Comment: So I found the partial derivatives of $f(1+t\cos\theta, 1 + t\sin\theta)$ at $t=0$ and got

$$f_t = 4\cos\theta - 2\sin\theta \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ f_\theta = 0$$

and now I set $f_t = 0$ and solve, thanks very much!

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't get what you mean (I have no problem with the question and the answer, though)

Comment: @TedShifrin May I ask why $1+ t\cos\theta$ and $1+t\sin\theta$?

Comment: @Ed_4434 I'm note sure what TedShifrin did is correct. Your exercice asks  : to find the equation of the tangent plane $T_p$ at $p = (x,y,z)$ (or $T_{(x,y)}$ since $p = (x,y,x^4-y^2)$) and then to find a point $q$ in that plane such that $\vec{pq}$ makes an angle $\theta$ with the vector $(1,0,0)$ ?

Comment: Ed, this is just a function of $t$, so no partial derivatives, just the derivative with respect to $t$. This is how we parametrize the line in the plane with direction $\theta$ (point $(1,1)$, direction vector $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$). @user1952009, no, there's no mention of a tangent plane. The function is a function of $(x,y)$ and the question asks at what rate it changes if we move in a certain direction from a certain point. BTW, Ed, if you check my profile, you'll see a link to 100+ YouTube lectures on an integrated (theoretical) course in linear algebra and multivariable calculus.

Comment: @TedShifrin the surface is $S = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3, z-x^4+y^2=0\}$ (or $\mathbb{C}^3$, it is the same), it has a tangent plane $T_p$ at each $p = (x,y,z) \in S$, nowhere it is mentioned to consider the parametrization $f(x,y) = x^4-y^2$ and to represent the tangent plane in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: @user1952009, I've taught multivariable calculus for over 40 years. You're making a much harder problem than is intended. Note that the problem itself says it's asking for a directional derivative. Review the definition, please.

Comment: @TedShifrin you can represent the tangent plane as you want, the thing is that you are considering an angle $\theta$ between $(1,0)$ and  $(\Delta x, \Delta y)$ (in $\mathbb{R}^2$ !) not between $(1,0,0)$ and $(\Delta x, \Delta y, \Delta z)$  (in $\mathbb{R}^3$ !) that makes a huge difference, and you loose the "Riemann surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$" aspect